# How to make regex in node.js return the first matching group?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a string from a text file from which I have to extract a value. Here's the line containing the value (there are many other lines):

```
<CONFIG_entry name="Konfiguration:Allgemeine Einstellungen:CMS-Server:Port" valuetext="15000" value="15000" adr="CL1.2.1" unit="" />
```

What I want to get out is the ***valuetext*** value:

```
15000
```

I fiddled around with an online Regex tester and ended up with this expression, which gave me exactly the value I was looking for (15000):

```
/CMS-Server:Port"\s+valuetext="(.*)"\s+value/
```

Next, I wanted to use this line in node.js like this:

```
var myFile = fs.readFileSync('myfile.txt','utf8');
var pattern = new RegExp(/CMS-Server:Port"\s+valuetext="(.*)"\s+value/);
var matches = myFile.match(pattern);
console.log("Result: " + matches[0]);
```

The problem: `matches[0]` gives me this

```
CMS-Server:Port" valuetext="15000" value
```

instead of

```
15000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `matches[1]` instead (which references the first group)

Comment: That's it, thank you! I somehow thought that *matches* is an array of all matches in the string when searching globally. Not sure what this downvoting is all about.. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify `g` modifier, that is why `match` returns the full match with `match[0]`, and the value of the first capturing group with `match[1]`.

If you specify `g`, then you will have an array of all matches, but no access to captured texts and you would have to use `exec`.

Also, you have a problem with the regex: `.*` may match much more than you need. Use `[^"]*` or `\d*` (since the field only contains digits) instead.

Besides, you can safely remove `new RegExp(...)`, just use `var pattern = /.../`.

So, I suggest

```
/CMS-Server:Port"\s+valuetext="(\d*)"\s+value/
....
console.log("Result: " + matches[1]);
```

Or use XML Parser:

```js
var myXML = '<CONFIG_entry name="Konfiguration:Allgemeine Einstellungen:CMS-Server:Port" valuetext="15000" value="15000" adr="CL1.2.1" unit="" />';
var parseXml;

if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" &&
       new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    throw new Error("No XML parser found");
}

var xml = parseXml(myXML);
alert(xml.documentElement.getAttribute("valuetext"));
```